# How to run mysql client command async in bash?

Tags: mysql, bash

Is it possible to run a `mysql` command async in `bash`? I tried the `&` operator at the end, but his causes the process to hang and not quit when the select finished.

Example:

```
export MYSQL_PWD=rootpw; mysql --user=root --database=my_table -e "SELECT 1" &
```

Running this command succeeds immediately *without* the `&`.
And with the `&` operator, it hangs and never exits. Why?

My goal is to trigger a long running table truncate (and other cleanup commands) while another aggregation process should already start before the truncate finished.

Comment: What is your business purpose to do it? Can CLI command 'screen' help you?

Comment: Added goal above..

Comment: do you wish to run the above command on CLI or inside a script ?

Comment: It should run in context of a larger existing bash script.

Comment: Are you sure you are truncating and not deleting?  Tuncate is a DDL statement that drops and recreates an existing table.